# Cast from Parent* to Child<T>* with unknown T, and get T

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have an object of type Child that has been initialized with unknown T. I need to create a new object of the same type T as this object. My object of type Child has an untemplated base class Parent. My only access to my object of type Child is through a pointer of type Parent. Is it possible to cast this pointer to Parent into a pointer to the correctly-templated type Child object? Or otherwise obtain T from the pointer to Parent?

The only examples I can find already know T when casting.

```
struct Parent{

};

template <typename T>
struct Child{
    typedef T    ValueType;

};

template <typename T>
void foo(Parent*) { }

// implementation

Parent* object; // provided from somewhere else, points to Child<T> of unknown T

foo<T>(object); // PROBLEM because T depends on what T the Child in object was templated with
```

Comment: Look at the "prototype" design pattern

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this (minimal example)?

```
struct Parent {
    virtual Parent * clone() = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct Child: Parent {
    Child<T> * clone() override {
        return new Child<T>;
    }
};

int main() {
    Child<int> *c = new Child<int>;
    Child<int> *cclone = c->clone();
    Parent *pclone = c->clone();
}
```

**EDIT**

Considering the snippet added by the OP with an edit, here is a slightly modified example (based on the same idea):

```
struct Parent;

template <typename T>
void foo(Parent*) { }

struct Parent{
    virtual void invokeFoo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Child: Parent {
    void invokeFoo() override {
        foo<T>(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Parent* object = new Child<int>;
    object->invokeFoo();
}
```

Comment: I added a short block of code to my OP to try and illustrate my problem better.

Comment: @pajosftw Added another example.